# Bundle regions, why language over region?

Tags: ios, ios10, regional-settings

The Apple Developer [Bundle Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-SW7) states that the search order for localized resources has the user's region setting taking precedence over the language setting. Using the iOS 10 simulator I'm not seeing that play out. My app has English-US, Spanish and Spanish-Paraguay localizations in its bundle. If I set the iPad language to English and the region to Paraguay, it still loads the English string at runtime. From reading the Bundle guide I thought region would take precedence? If I change the iPad language to Spanish, then the region kicks in and the Paraguay string is used (over the generic Spanish string) which is correct. What am I misunderstanding here about the search order?

What I'm *deducing* from all this, and I could be wrong, is perhaps iOS knows that if your region code ("es-PY" in this example) doesn't fall under the umbrella of your iOS language setting ("en" in this example), it just discards the region as invalid. In real world terms this makes some sense to me. In other words, having an English language setting and a Paraguay region is not really a real world scenario, right? So because my "en" doesn't match the lang portion of the region setting the es of the "**es**-PY", iOS says, "sorry, that makes no sense - ignoring".

Would love for someone to confirm these suspicions.

Comment: Beautifully argued.